# Как сделать ссылку на папку почты в Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Задача - сделать ссылку на локальную папку с письмами в почтовом клиенте Thunderbird.
Чтобы ее можно было использовать как ссылку к задаче таск-менеджера.
Клик - и открывается папка со всеми письмами по проекту.

В gmail это можно было решить банальным копированием URL нужной папки из строки браузера. 
Из плагинов к Thunderbird - нашел только Thunderlink, но он делает ссылки только на отдельное письмо.

Какие еще могут быть решения для локальной папки писем?